# GCC: Optimizing away memory loads and stores

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

**EDIT 1:** Added another example (showing that GCC is, in principle, be capable to do what I want to achieve) and some more discussion at the end of this question.

**EDIT 2:** Found the `malloc` function attribute, which *should* do what.  Please take a look at the very end of the question.

This is a question about how to tell the compiler that stores to a memory area are not visible outside of a region (and thus could be optimized away). To illustrate what I mean, let's take a look at the following code

```
int f (int a)
{
    int v[2];
    v[0] = a;
    v[1] = 0;
    while (v[0]-- > 0)
       v[1] += v[0];
    return v[1];
}
```

`gcc -O2` generates the following assembly code (x86-64 gcc, trunk, on https://godbolt.org):

```
f:
        leal    -1(%rdi), %edx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        testl   %edi, %edi
        jle     .L4
.L3:
        addl    %edx, %eax
        subl    $1, %edx
        cmpl    $-1, %edx
        jne     .L3
        ret
.L4:
        ret
```

As one can see, the loads and stores into the array `v` are gone after optimization.

Now consider the following code:

```
int g (int a, int *v)
{
    v[0] = a;
    v[1] = 0;
    while (v[0]-- > 0)
       v[1] += v[0];
    return v[1];
}
```

The difference is that `v` is not (stack-) allocated in the function, but provided as an argument.  The result of `gcc -O2` in this case is:

```
g:
        leal    -1(%rdi), %edx
        movl    $0, 4(%rsi)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    %edx, (%rsi)
        testl   %edi, %edi
        jle     .L4
.L3:
        addl    %edx, %eax
        subl    $1, %edx
        cmpl    $-1, %edx
        jne     .L3
        movl    %eax, 4(%rsi)
        movl    $-1, (%rsi)
        ret
.L4:
        ret
```

Clearly, the code has to store the final values of `v[0]` and `v[1]` in memory as they may be observable.

Now, what I am looking for is a way to tell the compiler that the memory pointed to by `v` in the second example isn't accessible any more after the function `g` has returned so that the compiler could optimize away the memory accesses.

To have an even simpler example:

```
void h (int *v)
{
    v[0] = 0;
}
```

If the memory pointed to by `v` isn't accessible after `h` returns, it should be possible to simplify the function to a single `ret`.

I tried to achieve what I want by playing with the strict aliasing rules but haven't succeeded.

**ADDED IN EDIT 1:**

GCC seems to have the necessary code built-in as the following example shows:

```
include <stdlib.h>

int h (int a)
{
    int *v = malloc (2 * sizeof (int));
    v[0] = a;
    v[1] = 0;
    while (v[0]-- > 0)
      v[1] += v[0];
    return v[1];
}
```

The generated code contains no loads and stores:

```
h:
        leal    -1(%rdi), %edx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        testl   %edi, %edi
        jle     .L4
.L3:
        addl    %edx, %eax
        subl    $1, %edx
        cmpl    $-1, %edx
        jne     .L3
        ret
.L4:
        ret
```

In other words, GCC knows that changing the memory area pointed to by `v` is not observable through any side-effect of `malloc`. For purposes like this one, GCC has `__builtin_malloc`.

So I can also ask: How can user code (say a user version of `malloc`) make use of this functionality?

**ADDED IN EDIT 2:**

GCC has the following function attribute:

> malloc
>
> This tells the compiler that a function is malloc-like, i.e., that the pointer P returned by the function cannot alias any other pointer valid when the function returns, and moreover no pointers to valid objects occur in any storage addressed by P.
>
> Using this attribute can improve optimization. Compiler predicts that a function with the attribute returns non-null in most cases. Functions like malloc and calloc have this property because they return a pointer to uninitialized or zeroed-out storage. However, functions like realloc do not have this property, as they can return a pointer to storage containing pointers.

It *seems* to do what I want as the following example shows:

```
__attribute__ (( malloc )) int *m (int *h);

int i (int a, int *h) 
{ 
    int *v = m (h);
    v[0] = a;
    v[1] = 0;
    while (v[0]-- > 0)
        v[1] += v[0];
    return v[1];
}
```

The generated assembler code has no loads and stores:

```
i:
        pushq   %rbx
        movl    %edi, %ebx
        movq    %rsi, %rdi
        call    m
        testl   %ebx, %ebx
        jle     .L4
        leal    -1(%rbx), %edx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
.L3:
        addl    %edx, %eax
        subl    $1, %edx
        cmpl    $-1, %edx
        jne     .L3
        popq    %rbx
        ret
.L4:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rbx
        ret
```

However, as soon as the compiler sees a definition of `m`, it may forget about the attribute. For example, this is the case when the following definition is given:

```
__attribute__ (( malloc )) int *m (int *h)
{
    return h;
}
```

In that case, the function is inlined and the compiler forgets about the attribute, yielding the same code as the function `g`.

**P.S.:** Initially, I thought that the `restrict` keyword may help, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Uhm could you provide a real-world case where this could be useful? If "the outside" doesn't care about the state of the buffer cannot you just allocate it locally? Or is it because it's some kind of user-supplied scratch buffer?

Comment: In the real-world use case, the buffer is supplied by a memory management system with GC. Allocating on the stack isn't possible, say with `alloca`, because I need TCO to work and because I need the stack space be strictly bounded.

Comment: What if `g()` is invoked from another module? It must adhere to the declaration. If you make it `inline`, *then* it may be optimized at the call site.

Comment: Why don't you use inlining or allocate a local copy as long as the local copy fits into registers and thus doesn't contribute to stack usage? Why do you need stack space strictly bounded. Can't you account for the stack space used by the function?

Comment: My real world code is not written by hand but generated by a transpiler. The transpiler doesn't know what the largest buffer is that fits into local variables, etc. Thus I have been looking for a general solution.

Comment: I looked through the GCC extensions (not exhaustively, just likely categories) and do not see anything that would provide the requested function. In theory, `unsigned char a[1]; memset(v, a[1], length);` would accomplish this by setting `v` to an “indeterminate” value, which could allow the compiler to optimize knowing both that anything written to `v` previously is not subsequently used and that the `memset` is not actually needed. (Although it nominally sets all of `v` to one value, “indeterminate” allows otherwise.) But I doubt the compiler will actually behave as desired in this situation.

Comment: Sky Computer’s C compiler did have such an extension, in the late 1990s. So it is not unheard of or unreasonable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Something like the `memset` trick you are suggesting would at least partially accomplish what I am looking for. Compared with the example code of the function `f`, where everything is allocated on the stack, I still would have to explicitly invalidate the pointer.

Comment: @Marc the edit  does not show anything because the scope of the pointer is this function. The only global effect is a memory leak. So it does not matter how do you allocate the memory for it. Even if the allocated memory is global when you leave the function you loose the reference to it and its content cannot be observed.

Comment: @P__J__ The memory leak is irrelevant to the discussion. I left out the `free` because it does not matter for the question at hand (inserting it is not harmful either). My point is the following: If `malloc` was a user-supplied function defined in another translation unit, the compiler cannot know that all references to the memory pointed to by `v` are lost (in fact, they aren't when the built-in `malloc` is used but still the contents do not matter). However, the compiler has some special knowledge about the built-in `malloc`. How can I tell the compiler this about user-written functions?

Comment: Found `__attribute__ (( malloc ))`, which could help. See my second edit above.

Comment: One needs `noinline` as well; see my answer.

Comment: @Marc no it is not. Because your `i` vanishes when function exits and the external world will not have access to the allocated space. That is the reason why this function has no side effects. External world do not have any references to the allocated memory.

Comment: @P__J__ Through the data structures maintained by `malloc`, the external world has references to the allocated memory. However, through `__builtin_malloc`, GCC is smart enough to know that such references would cause UB.

Comment: Ok tell me how any other function in your program can access this allocated space if you say that the external world has an access.

Comment: @P__J__ Imagine, GCC has no built-in support for `malloc`. In that case, it wouldn't matter (to the compiler) if I switched glibc's `malloc` definition with my own over which I have full control. Or I look into the internals of glibc. Or I read `/proc/XXX/mem` on GNU/Linux. The point is that all of this would cause UB by the C standard, which the compiler knows, so it can optimize out the memory accesses.

Comment: gcc has an internal notion of clobber (used for instance when variables go out of scope), but no convenient way for users to add them.

Comment: @MarcGlisse How would this notion help in this case (assuming it was accessible for the user)?

Comment: @Marc (looks like I am talking to myself) It would let the compiler know that whatever was written there is now dead. Just like what you wrote to a variable is dead once the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: @MarcGlisse :-) What you propose seems to be the `memset` trick by Eric Postpischil (see above).

Comment: Except that gcc doesn't yet turn writes of uninitialized values into clobbers, so it doesn't optimize as you would like. But yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Discussion about the `noinline` attribute added at the end.

Using the following function definition, one can achieve the goal of my question:

```
__attribute__ (( malloc, noinline )) static void *get_restricted_ptr (void *p)
{
    return p;
}
```

This function `get_restricted_ptr` simply returns its pointer argument but informs the compiler that the returned pointer P cannot alias any other pointer valid when the function returns, and moreover no pointers to valid objects occur in any storage addressed by P.

The use of this function is demonstrated here:

```
int i (int a, int *h)
{
    int *v = get_restricted_ptr (h);
    v[0] = a;
    v[1] = 0;
    while (v[0]-- > 0)
        v[1] += v[0];
    return;
}
```

The generated code does not contain loads and stores:

```
i:
        leal    -1(%rdi), %edx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        testl   %edi, %edi
        jle     .L6
.L5:
        addl    %edx, %eax
        subl    $1, %edx
        cmpl    $-1, %edx
        jne     .L5
        ret
.L6:
        ret
```

**ADDED IN EDIT:** If the `noinline` attribute is left out, GCC ignores the `malloc` attribute.  Apparently, in this case, the function gets inlined first so that there is no function call any more for which GCC would check the `malloc` attribute. (One can discuss whether this behaviour should be considered a bug in GCC.)  With the `noinline` attribute, the function doesn't get inlined. Then, due to the `malloc` attribute, GCC understands that the call to that function is unnecessary and removes it completely.

Unfortunately, this means that the (trivial) function won't be inlined when its call is not eliminated due to the `malloc` attribute.

Comment: This answer should discuss the need for `noinline`, as it is not apparent why it should be needed. (Is it a bug in GCC support for the `malloc` attribute or due to something else?)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point; I added two paragraphs. Unfortunately, as observed in the second added paragraph, using `noinline` has some adverse effects. I'm still hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Why would adding the malloc attribute allow the compiler to eliminate the call?

Answer (score 0):

Both functions have side effects and memory reads & stores cannot be optimized out

```
void h (int *v)
{
    v[0] = 0;
}
```

and

```
int g (int a, int *v)
{
    v[0] = a;
    v[1] = 0;
    while (v[0]-- > 0)
       v[1] += v[0];
    return v[1];
}
```

The side effects have to be observable outside the function scope. Inline functions may have another behavior as the side effect might have to be observable outside the enclosing code.

```
inline int g (int a, int *v)
{
    v[0] = a;
    v[1] = 0;
    while (v[0]-- > 0)
       v[1] += v[0];
    return v[1];
}

void h(void)
{
    int x[2],y ;

    g(y,x);
}
```

this code will be optimized to just a simple return

You can promise the compiler that nothing will happen to allow easier optimizations by using keyword restrict. But of course your code must keep this promise.

Comment: My point is that I want to convince the compiler that the side effects won't be observable, in which case it could optimize them out.

Comment: The question asks about GCC specifically. Do you know that GCC has no extension by which it might be informed that the contents of `v` are not needed when `g` returns?

Comment: Indeed, persuading GCC would be enough.

Comment: No. There is no way.

Comment: @P__J__ Internally, the compiler seems to have a way as my added example with `malloc` shows.

Comment: @Marc it does not show anything because the scope oof the pointer is this function. The only global effect is a memory leak. So it does not matter how do you allocate the memory for it.

Answer (score 0):

For C, the only restriction is that the compiler has to ensure that the code behaves the same. If the compiler can prove that the code behaves the same then it can and will remove the stores.

For example, I put this into https://godbolt.org/ :

```
void h (int *v)
{
    v[0] = 0;
}

void foo() {
    int v[2] = {1, 2};
    h(v);
}
```

And told it to use GCC 8.2 and "-O3", and got this output:

```
h(int*):
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 0
        ret
foo():
        ret
```

Note that there are **two different versions of the function `h()` in the output**. The first version exists in case other code (in other object files) want to use the function (and may be discarded by the linker). The second version of `h()` was inlined directly into `foo()` and then optimised down to absolutely nothing.

If you change the code to this:

```
static void h (int *v)
{
    v[0] = 0;
}

void foo() {
    int v[2] = {1, 2};
    h(v);
}
```

Then it tells the compiler that the version of `h()` that only existed for linking with other object files isn't needed, so the compiler only generates the second version of `h()` and the output becomes this:

```
foo():
        ret
```

Of course all optimizers in all compiler's aren't perfect - for more complex code (and for different compilers including different versions of GCC) results might be different (the compiler may fail to do this optimization). This is purely a limitation of the compiler's optimizer and not a limitation of C itself.

For cases where the compiler's optimiser isn't good enough, there are 4 possible solutions:

- get a better compiler
- improve the compiler's optimiser (e.g. send an email with to the compiler's developers that includes a minimal example and cross your fingers)
- modify the code to make it easier for the compiler's optimiser (e.g. copy the input array into a local array, like "`void h(int *v) { int temp[2]; temp[0] = v[0]; temp[1] = v[1]; ...` ).
- shrug and say "Oh, that's a pity" and do nothing

Comment: This answer says that the compiler can do the desired optimization if it can see the all the relevant code. But the question is seeking a solution for when the calling code is not visible. Since it asks about GCC, not just standard C, the solution may be a GCC extension, not standard C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: To me, OP's "not visible outside of a region" means "outside the function" and not "in a different compilation unit". For the latter, you need link time optimisation if you want to optimise across compilation units.

Comment: The OP explicitly asks: “Now, what I am looking for is a way to tell the compiler that the memory pointed to by `v` in the second example isn't accessible any more after the function `g` has returned so that the compiler could optimize away the memory accesses.” You do not need link-time optimization if there is a compiler extension to do as they ask.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: You also don't need link-time optimisation if the OP is mistakenly thinking that the optimisation wasn't done because they're looking at the wrong version of the function (the version that will be discarded at link time and not the version/s that will be used in the same compilation unit).

Comment: @Brendan Eric Postpischil is right. In my case even whole program optimization wouldn't necessarily help. Whatever `v` points to will eventually be garbage collected by my GC but there is no way for the compiler to know that the values in this part of the heap won't be accessed any more.

Comment: @Marc what GC? C does not have one

Comment: @P__J__ The heap is not `malloc`'s heap but a custom one with a custom GC collector (implemented in user code).

Comment: @Marc: In that case, see the "cases where the compiler's optimiser isn't good enough" part at the end; especially that last option (caring about the cost of a few weeny stores while you've got a honking great GC destroying any hope of performance is a bit like worrying about having your fingernails cut while an alligator is eating both of your legs)

Comment: @Brendan The garbage collector is a copying one. Its cost is proportional to the size of the non-garbage. In the example above, the allocated `v` is dead at the end of the function, so GC time is zero in this case. (The cost of the allocation is just adding a constant to a pointer, which can even live in a register.)

Comment: @Marc: Cheney's algorithm? In that case you mean loads of CPU time is wasted copying "non-garbage" and when you're finished the caches are all polluted, so performance sucks while you're collecting garbage (especially for multi-threaded) and then performance sucks after you've collected garbage (due to cache misses).

Comment: @Brendan: I described the first generation part of the GC. The performance implications you describe depend on how often the GC has to run, I think. As long as the GC does not have to run during hot loops, all that counts is that allocation is fast.